# How to use files conditionally in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to use a file conditionally upon user input. I am using WooCommerce templates in my child theme. Of course, the file (`content-single-product.php`) is customized in the child theme. However, I also wish to give users an option to use the default WC file if they want to. In short, I want to use that file conditionally which user will choose.

I am using the PHP `copy()` and `unlink()` functions. I just want your expert opinion if this is the best solution or if you have any suggestions better than mine. Here are the functions in my child theme.

```
/*...for copying the file from a child theme folder to the woocommerce folder...*/
function ac_wc_files_to_theme()
{
    $theme_dir =  get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/files/content-single-product.php';
    $theme_dir_file  = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/content-single-product.php';

    if (!copy($theme_dir, $theme_dir_file)) {
        echo "failed to copy $theme_dir to $theme_dir_file...\n";
    }
}

 /*...for removing the file from a the woocommerce folder...*/

function ac_wc_delete_wc_file(){

    $fileArray = array(
    get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/content-single-product.php'
   );

foreach ($fileArray as $value) {
    if (file_exists($value)) {
        unlink($value);
    } else {
        echo 'file not found';
    }
}
}

/*...calling the options from the theme settings area....*/


if (get_option('ac_wc_default_single') == 1) {
add_action('init', 'ac_wc_delete_wc_file');
remove_action('init', 'ac_wc_files_to_theme');
}
else {
add_action('init', 'ac_wc_files_to_theme');
remove_action('init', 'ac_wc_delete_wc_file');
}
```

The codes are working fine. Just I need your view if this will do. Thanks

Comment: Instead of copying files around, I think you might be able to achieve your aim of toggling between the theme and woocommerce's version of templates by filtering [`woocommerce_locate_template`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/927941e2cad28903a2d0bd03ce52a8809525f4e3/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L256).

Comment: Thanks. I tried with this but this does not seem to work. Can you suggest?

function ac_wc_override_single_product($template, $template_name, $template_path) { 

if ($template_name == 'content-single-product.php') { 
$template_path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/files/content-single-product-1.php'; 

$template = $template_path;
} 
return $template; 
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_locate_template', 'ac_wc_override_single_product', 20, 3);

Comment: In the future, can you edit your question to add the new code? Code in the comments is awfully hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best guess at filtering the template without extensive testing.

```
// change the default template path to `woocommerce/files`
function ac_wc_override_template_path(){
    return 'woocommerce/files/';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_template_path', 'ac_wc_override_template_path' );


// now filter the woocommerce template
function ac_wc_override_single_product($template, $template_name, $template_path) { 
    $alt_template = '';

    if ($template_name == 'content-single-product.php') { 
        $alt_template = locate_template( trailingslashit( $template_path ) . 'content-single-product-1.php' );
    } 

    if( $alt_template && get_option( 'use_my_themes_templates' ) ){
        return $alt_template;
    } else {
        return $template;
    } 
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_locate_template', 'ac_wc_override_single_product', 20, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks it sorta worked for me but I am getting the notice undefined variable : alt_template when the options are not selected meaning when user wants to use the default template of WC. No issue since I am adding the filter conditionally now

Comment: Ahh... that's because if you aren't on `content-single-product.php` then `$alt_template` isn't defined. That's easy enough to fix, see my edit.